# How does the diode clamper circuit clamp

Tags: diodes, level-shifting

If you look at the standard Clamper circuit(using diode and capacitor), we a load taking across diode(resistor in parallel to R), but what makes no sense is, if R and diode D in parallel, then aren't there points where the load voltage(Vout) just gets clamped to diode voltage of apps 0.7 V?

[image]

Also, how would I clamp a regular(0-Vcc) square wave to a (-Vcc to +Vcc) square wave using opamps.

[Reference](http://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/electronic-devices-and-circuits/rectifier/clampercircuits.html)

Comment: It explains fully in your link how this works ....did you read the explanation?

Comment: it makes no sense to me somwhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually gets clamped to around -0.7V from the perspective of the load. Perhaps a simulation will make it clearer to you what is happening.

[Falstad Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+25.510281670702206+54+5+50%0Av+208+480+208+240+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+336+480+208+480+0%0Aw+336+240+416+240+0%0Aw+336+480+416+480+0%0Ag+336+480+336+512+0%0Aw+416+240+480+240+0%0Ar+208+240+272+240+0+0.1%0Ac+336+240+272+240+0+0.001+4.433171020631968%0Ad+336+480+336+240+1+0.805904783%0Ar+416+240+416+480+0+10000%0Ao+0+64+0+4354+10+0.00009765625+0+2+0+3%0Ao+5+64+0+4354+10+0.1+1+2+5+3%0A)

For your second question you would AC couple the square wave into the op amp biased to ground and provide a gain of 2. Sim link below.

[Falstad Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+15.472767971186109+50+5+50%0Aa+304+336+416+336+1+15+-15+1000000+-2.6691180549524662+-2.669171437313565%0AR+192+320+128+320+0+2+40+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0Ac+192+320+304+320+0+0.00009999999999999999+2.669171437313565%0Ar+304+416+416+416+0+10000%0Ar+304+416+304+528+0+10000%0Aw+304+352+304+416+0%0Ag+304+528+304+560+0%0Aw+416+416+416+336+0%0Aw+416+336+480+336+0%0Ar+304+320+304+176+0+10000%0Ag+304+176+240+176+0%0Ao+1+32+0+4354+10+0.00009765625+0+2+1+3%0Ao+8+32+0+12546+5.411089519363607+0.0001+1+2+8+3%0A)